# Client is not paying for my work - legal actions

Tags: legal, payment-terms, difficult-client, payments, late-payment

I did a project for a client (it was around 3000$). It was monthly support project and as per agreement he has to pay monthly 1200$. But for 3 months, he didn't pay anything.
First time, he literally cried over the call, he has financial problem he can't pay this month...but he will get his salary very soon then he will pay. So I trusted him (here I did mistake) and I continued his work. But After 3 months also he just paid only 600$ and again he started crying. This time I stopped my work and started asking for rest of  the amount. I sent him unlimited mails with reminder but he never responded. If I call him he always pick up my call and says this time he will definitely transfer my money.

My client was an employee in a reputed company and I was doing his job after taking his half salary. (I don't know how did he get that job even).

How can I screw him up legally? I have just our communication mails.

Comment: Signed contract? If not, you've already lost any battle.

Comment: It was not signed contract but I have mails from his official id and his personal id.

Comment: I believe small claims is your only legal option. You have to *prove* there's a debt first.

Answer (score 2):

Your options are:

- Sue the client in **small claims court**, which is a legal remedy for claims less than some statutory amount. It's a somewhat common thing in the US, and there are many TV reality shows about small claims cases (*Judge Judy* being the first and possibly the most popular). I don't know about the existence of such courts outside the US.
- Sell the debt to a **collection agency** or hire a collection agent to attempt to collect the money owed. You will not get the full amount in either case, but you might get something and collection agents are very good at bothering people to pay up money owed to third parties. Again, these entities are subject to local laws/ordinances.

Comment: I am not aware of "small claims court". Can you please elaborate on this?

Comment: Hi Voxwoman, can you [edit] to expand your answer? This is quite low in quality, and may be deleted. If you have any questions, please drop by the [chat], and I'd be willing to help.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to report him to his employer and show proofs of the contract and what payment is due to you.

By the way, are you both in the same country?

Comment: We both are from same country but he was working in different country

Comment: Hi Tosin, welcome to Freelancing.SE! Can you please [edit] to expand your answer? This is quite low in quality, and may be deleted. If you have any questions, please drop by the [chat], and I'd be willing to help.